# knockout.mapping issue displaying observable function code

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, knockout-mapping-plugin

I am getting issue with knockout mapping plugin displaying observable function code rather than unwrapped value in the binding.
It only happens when I fetch knockout.js from internet, if I use my local copy of knockout.js it works fine.

```
index.html
--------------
<DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Require Demo</title>
<script type="text/javascript" data-main="scripts/main.js" src="scripts/require.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="vm1" data-bind="text: timeWhenLoaded"></div>
<div id="vm2" data-bind="text: timeWhenLoaded"></div> <!-- Issue: shows code of observable function, not the value -->

</body>
</html>

scripts/main.js
---------------------
require.config({
    baseUrl: 'scripts/lib',
    paths: {
        app: '../app',
        helper: '../helper'
    }
});

require(["https://github.com/knockout/knockout/releases/download/v3.0.0/knockout-3.0.0.debug.js", "knockout.mapping", "helper/utils"], function(knockout, mapping, utils) {
//require(["knockout", "knockout.mapping", "helper/utils"], function(knockout, mapping, utils) { // works fine

    console.log('time when loaded: ' + utils.timeWhenLoaded());

    function _vm () {
        this.timeWhenLoaded = knockout.observable(utils.timeWhenLoaded());
    }
    var vm1 = new _vm();

    var vm2 = mapping.fromJS({
        timeWhenLoaded: utils.timeWhenLoaded()
    });

    knockout.applyBindings(vm1, document.getElementById('vm1'));
    knockout.applyBindings(vm2, document.getElementById('vm2'));

});

scripts/helper/utils.js
------------------------------
define(function(){
    var now = Date.now();

    function timeWhenLoaded() {
        return new Date(now).toString();
    }

    return {
        timeWhenLoaded: timeWhenLoaded
    };
});

scripts/lib/knockout.js
scripts/lib/knockout.mapping.js
```

Comment: are you sure that your knockout.mapping.js file is requiring the knockout base class as a dependency?